# Create a ratings wall from JSON file

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to create a "Ratings wall" which is a table that shows people's ratings of a place. The ratings are accessed from a JSON file (ratings.json) and are then displayed on the wall. The problem I'm having is I want the star rating that the person has given the place to appear on the wall in the form of yellow stars. The process I use for this is to: Use a for loop to  get all of the ratings, (they are only a number (1-5), so the output would look like "152423". And I want each number for each persons rating to show up in star form so my desired result would look something like this: [Desired Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tKMV.png)

But at the moment, the stars are appearing, but $rating seems to be defined as 5 for some reason. I feel like it has something to do with the JSON being decoded and the $decode[$i]['rating'] being in array form.

Any help would be appreciated.

Code below:

```
    <html>
  <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="comments.css" />
  <title>Lonely Bris</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table class="table">
    <?php
      $output = file_get_contents("ratings.json");
      $decode = json_decode($output, true);
      
      for($i = 0; $i < count($decode); $i++) {
        $decode[$i]['rating'];
        $rating = $decode[$i]['rating'];     
      }

      $star = '<div class="rate"><input type="radio" id="star" name="rate"/><label for="star" title="text">1 star</label></div>';

      if($rating == 1){
       $rating = str_repeat($star, 1);
      }
      elseif($rating == 2){
        $rating = str_repeat($star, 2);
      }
      elseif($rating == 3){
       $rating = str_repeat($star, 3);
      }
      elseif($rating == 4){
       $rating = str_repeat($star, 4);
      }
      elseif($rating == 5){
        $rating = str_repeat($star, 5);
      }
      else{
        $rating = "Unknown.";
      }
      echo "<tr><th></th><th>Review</th><th>Rating</th><th>Image?</th></tr>";
      
      for($i = 0; $i < count($decode); $i++) {

      $imgUrl = $decode[$i]['image'];

      echo "<tr class=border_bottom><td>" . "<div class=name>" . $decode[$i]['name'] . "</div>" . " - " . $rating . "<br><br>" . $decode[$i]['review'] . "</td>";
    ?>
    <td><img src="<?php echo $imgUrl; ?>" height="70" width="120" class="img-thumbnail" /></td></tr>
    <?php   
      }
    ?>
  </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

JSON file (ratings.json)

```
[
    {
        "name": "James",
        "event": "Test",
        "review": "Test",
        "rating": "5",
        "image": "http:\/\/localhost\/ClassIA3\/images\/RobloxScreenShot20210104_132131740.png"
    },
    {
        "name": "Sup",
        "event": "The Storytellers",
        "review": "Test",
        "rating": "5",
        "image": "http:\/\/localhost\/ClassIA3\/images\/RobloxScreenShot20201012_195012147.png"
    },
    {
        "name": "Pont",
        "event": "ACTivate children's club for 3-4 years",
        "review": "Test",
        "rating": "4",
        "image": "http:\/\/localhost\/ClassIA3\/images\/RobloxScreenShot20210101_181318133.png"
    },
    {
        "name": "Hello2",
        "event": "Flexibility and core training",
        "review": "Was so good for my core",
        "rating": "5",
        "image": "http:\/\/localhost\/ClassIA3\/images\/RobloxScreenShot20201120_213311711.png"
    },
    {
        "name": "Hello2",
        "event": "The Letter 'B'",
        "review": "SO Cool",
        "rating": "1",
        "image": "http:\/\/localhost\/ClassIA3\/images\/untitled.png"
    },
    {
        "name": "Sup",
        "event": "Dragon boating",
        "review": "Origami!",
        "rating": "4",
        "image": "http:\/\/localhost\/ClassIA3\/images\/Capture.PNG"
    },
    {
        "name": "Hello2",
        "event": "Brisbane Greeters - Paddington walking tour",
        "review": "I loved it!",
        "rating": "5",
        "image": "http:\/\/localhost\/ClassIA3\/images\/OLD TECH ROOMS.jpg"
    }
]
```

Comment: Please read about `str_repeat()`.

Comment: @mickmackusa Thanks, I've updated the code and the question, should make more sense now.

Comment: Or even `$rating = in_array($rating, range(1, 5)) ? str_repeat($star, $rating) : 'Unknown.';`.  I am at work, I do not have time to read your question fully.

Comment: Oh okay. Well cheers for the help anyway.

Comment: My comment might be seen as "off topic" but I would strongly suggest to do the actual markup clientside, using JavaScript. This would keep your code cleaner and will reduce server load and network traffic. JavaScript can deal very well with JSON and you can use `String.prototype.repeat(num)` for your stars too.

Comment: @CarstenMassmann Thanks for the advice, but I don't know JavaScript from a bar of soap. So I can't implement it even if I tried.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things to fix/improve.

Most critically, `$rating = $decode[$i]['rating'];` in your first loop is overwriting the same variable `$rating` over and over.  When the loop finishes, `$rating` will be the value accessed in the final iteration -- this is why you always see five stars with your sample data.

Furthermore, `$decode[$i]['rating'];` in the first loop does nothing; just delete the line of code.

To make your dynamically generated html easier to read, I recommend a basic template string with placeholders -- this way you do need to use interpolation or concatenation to mix static text with variables.

I don't know what your intention is with the radio inputs, but `id` attributes must be unique in a valid html document.  The `name` attributes between different sets of stars in the same form will also be in conflict -- again, I don't know your intent.

Use css to implement styling.  Use classes to style repeating elements.

Only use html tables to present tabular data.  It is not recommended/modern to abuse table as a way to "grid" general html layout.

Recommended Starting Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/kV39k))

```
$rowTemplate = <<<ROWTEMPLATE
    <tr class="border_bottom">
        <td class="event">%s</td>
        <td class="name">%s</td>
        <td class="review">%s</td>
        <td class="rating">%s</td>
        <td><img class="img-thumbnail" src="%s"/></td>
    </tr>

ROWTEMPLATE;

?>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>Event</th>
        <th>Reviewer</th>
        <th>Review</th>
        <th>Rating</th>
        <th>Image?</th>
    </tr>
<?php
    foreach (json_decode($json) as $obj) {
        printf(
            $rowTemplate,
            $obj->event,
            $obj->name,
            $obj->review,
            $obj->rating,
            $obj->image,
        );    
    }
?>
</table>
```

From this, you can replace `$obj->rating` in `printf()` with whatever repeating graphical markup that you wish.