# Issue with foreach, if, else php

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, foreach, wordpress-theming

I have been trying to add else to my foreach loop where it shows categories and subcategories. But if there is no categories available then I want it to show a text where it tells that there is no categories or products in categories.

Right now it shows the text that there is no products in categories anyways even if there is some categories shown.

```
<?php

  $taxonomy     = 'product_cat';
  $orderby      = 'menu_order';  
  $show_count   = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
  $pad_counts   = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
  $hierarchical = 1;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no  
  $title        = '';  
  $empty        = 1;

  $args = array(
         'taxonomy'     => $taxonomy,
         'orderby'      => $orderby,
         'show_count'   => $show_count,
         'pad_counts'   => $pad_counts,
         'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
         'title_li'     => $title,
         'hide_empty'   => $empty
  );
 $all_categories = get_categories( $args );
 
      echo '<ul>';
      echo '<div class="category"><h1>CATEGORIES</h1></div>';
 
 foreach ($all_categories as $cat) {
    if($cat->category_parent == 0) {
        $category_id = $cat->term_id; 
        
         echo '<li class="parentcategory">';
        echo '<a href="'. get_term_link($cat->slug, 'product_cat') .'">'. $cat->name .'</a>';
        echo '</li>';
        

        $args2 = array(
                'taxonomy'     => $taxonomy,
                'child_of'     => 0,
                'parent'       => $category_id,
                'orderby'      => $orderby,
                'show_count'   => $show_count,
                'pad_counts'   => $pad_counts,
                'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
                'title_li'     => $title,
                'hide_empty'   => $empty
        );
        $sub_cats = get_categories( $args2 );
        if($sub_cats) {
            foreach($sub_cats as $sub_category) {
                echo '<li class="subcategory">';
                echo  '<a href="'. get_term_link($sub_category->slug, 'product_cat') .'">'. $sub_category->name .'</a>' ;
                echo '</li>';
            }   
        } 
    }    
else {
          echo '<li>';
          echo '<p>';
          echo 'Currently there is no categories made';
          echo ' or any products in the categories';
          echo '</p>';
          echo '</li>';

   } 
}

 echo '</ul>';
 
?>
```

[image]

Comment: I'm really sorry to say this, and I haven't checked if anyone else has said it - but consistent spacing is important for everyone (that includes you). My *very first initial* review of the code left me wondering what was happening, because I was expecting consistent spacing. I don't care if you want tabs, or 3 spaces, or 1 space (in the case of a few things here) - but like, stick with it. This is something that will only harm you in the long run

Comment: Actually, now that I space it properly - I suspect you'll see your issue if you do that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your if statement is in a foreach loop so if there is category it writes the name of that category. When there is no category (or category_parrent isn't equals to 0 [$cat->category_parent ==0] then) in the last loop it goes into the else statement and tells you that there is category. Just make a if statement before the foreach loop

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Doğuş I came up with this solution. I added a  `if( !empty($all_categories) ){` before foreach loop and it seems to be working like it's supposed to. It shows categories when there is some and where there isn't it shows the text.

If anyone has a better solution please post your answer.

```
<?php

  $taxonomy     = 'product_cat';
  $orderby      = 'menu_order';  
  $show_count   = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
  $pad_counts   = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
  $hierarchical = 1;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no  
  $title        = '';  
  $empty        = 1;

  $args = array(
         'taxonomy'     => $taxonomy,
         'orderby'      => $orderby,
         'show_count'   => $show_count,
         'pad_counts'   => $pad_counts,
         'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
         'title_li'     => $title,
         'hide_empty'   => $empty
  );
 $all_categories = get_categories( $args );
 
      echo '<ul>';
      echo '<div class="categories"><h1>CATEGORIES</h1></div>';
 
 
  if( !empty($all_categories) ){
 
 foreach ($all_categories as $cat) {
    if($cat->category_parent == 0) {
        $category_id = $cat->term_id; 
        
         echo '<li class="parentcategory">';
        echo '<a href="'. get_term_link($cat->slug, 'product_cat') .'">'. $cat->name .'</a>';
        echo '</li>';
        

        $args2 = array(
                'taxonomy'     => $taxonomy,
                'child_of'     => 0,
                'parent'       => $category_id,
                'orderby'      => $orderby,
                'show_count'   => $show_count,
                'pad_counts'   => $pad_counts,
                'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
                'title_li'     => $title,
                'hide_empty'   => $empty
        );
        $sub_cats = get_categories( $args2 );
        if($sub_cats) {
            foreach($sub_cats as $sub_category) {
                echo '<li class="subcategory">';
                echo  '<a href="'. get_term_link($sub_category->slug, 'product_cat') .'">'. $sub_category->name .'</a>' ;
                echo '</li>';
            }   
        } 
    }    
 } }
else {
     
    

          echo '<li>';
          echo '<p>';
          echo 'Currently there is no categories made';
          echo ' or any products in the categories';
          echo '</p>';
          echo '</li>';
   
   } 

 echo '</ul>';
 
?>
```

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_categories/  `get_categories()` returns an array unconditionally.  If the array is empty, the `foreach()` will not iterate.  using `!empty()` is senseless.  `if($sub_cats) {` was just fine to use to check for a non empty array.

Comment: Did you mean if($all_categories) ?

Comment: Right.  `if($all_categories)`  And `if($sub_cats) {` is unnecessary because you are not doing anything special in an `else` when `$sub_cats` is empty.  The `foreach()` will only iterate if the passed in array is non-empty.

Comment: You might find your echos to be cleaner if you use `printf()`.  For just one example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68116911/2943403  This cuts down on interpolation/concatenation.